# Raster to ascii tool converting all data to one value (ArcMap)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, ascii

I am having an issue when converting a raster to ascii. With extract by mask I have selected the area I am interested in and subsequently resampled the data from 5km to 2 by 2 m (required for use in modelling system). I need the raster to be in ascii format and using the raster to ascii seems to change all the data to one value. I have used this methodology numbers of times before and this has never caused this issue before.

I wonder if anyone may have any ideas?

[image: Clipped and resampled data.][image: Raster to ascii conversion.]

Comment: Have you opened the ascii file to see what is there? Are the numbers there correct?

Comment: In notepad the initial lines read as follows:ncols         3650
nrows         2850
xllcorner     515299.9809
yllcorner     443292.6606
cellsize      2
NODATA_value  -9999

Comment: Do you see 624, 633 etc. further down in the file?

Comment: Sorry - I somehow exceeded a 5 min editing timeout...

In notepad the initial lines read as follows:
ncols         3650
nrows         2850
xllcorner     515299.9809
yllcorner     443292.6606
cellsize      2
NODATA_value  -9999

Followed by many lines of -9999 with the odd line of actual data (lines of numbers ranging between 624 and 641). I assume the no data points are points outside the area of interest, but inside the dataframe (if it were a rectangle). This would indicate that a differentiation in values is at least still present in the raw data?

Comment: Yes, I would conclude that the export to ascii has gone OK and you can concentrate on how you are visualising it back in ArcMap. (you should have loads of 633, 635, 641, 624's in your ascii file)

Comment: @DavidW Many thanks for your thoughts. The issue was also that an alternative software (SAGA-Gis) was not recognizing different values and the subsequent model output was erroneous. After a system restart both Arc and Saga are now for whatever reason representing the data values for the ascii file.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to add content. Comments are a way for others to request improvements.